# Gstreamer gst-launch udpsrc in ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, gst-launch

I'm trying to save multicast h264 ts to file using this command in gstreamer in ubuntu 16.04:

"gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc multicast-iface=eno1  uri=udp://224.1.1.1:3001 ! queue ! filesink location=test.mp4"

This command works in gstreamer on windows but when I try the same command in linux it doesn't work- test.mp4 file is created but nothing is written in it.

I also tried to play uri=udp://224.1.1.1:3001 in vlc and it can't play it either in ubuntu. In windows it works.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have mentioned anaconda path in bashrc, comment it, and relaunch the terminal. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like firewall is blocking. You need to enable the port, probably if you look using wireshark you might see the packets.

To disable firewall refer to **[1]**, doing this will enable the port and you should be able to get the udp packets.

**[1]** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

In wireshark I can see the packets.

firewall status is already 'inactive' so I guess that's not the issue...